# EBS R12.2 Register Scan Listener with PDB Oracle 19c database

Tags: oracle

I have installed 2 RAC node.

From database home after sourcing PDB environment file.

I am able to connect to PDB in sql developer using VIP1 or VIP2 on port1536.

I have cluster how to register it with cluster so that tns ping returns scan ips instead of vips.
I have already registered database and instances in cluster.
Already registered database and instances with grid and can see entries also.

```
srvctl add database -db <DB_NAME> -oraclehome /u01/app/oracle/product/19.3.0/dbhome_1
srvctl add instance -db <DB_NAME> -instance <SID_1> -node <HOSTNAME_1>
srvctl add instance -db <DB_NAME> -instance <SID_2> -node <HOSTNAME_2>

ps -eaf|grep tns
root         39      2  0 Aug05 ?        00:00:00 [netns]
grid       7506      1  0 Aug05 ?        00:00:02 /u01/app/19.3.0/grid/bin/tnslsnr LISTENER -no_crs_notify -inherit
grid      10520      1  0 Aug05 ?        00:00:25 /u01/app/19.3.0/grid/bin/tnslsnr ASMNET1LSNR_ASM -no_crs_notify -inherit
grid      10840      1  0 Aug05 ?        00:00:04 /u01/app/19.3.0/grid/bin/tnslsnr LISTENER_SCAN1 -no_crs_notify -inherit
oracle    21967      1  0 Aug05 ?        00:00:02 /u01/app/oracle/product/19.3.0/dbhome_1/bin/tnslsnr <DB_SID> -inherit
grid      62936  62791  0 19:49 pts/4    00:00:00 grep --color=auto tns

Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION_LIST= (LOAD_BALANCE=YES) (FAILOVER=YES) (DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=<VIP1>)(PORT=1536)) (CONNECT_DATA= (SERVICE_NAME=ebs_<PDB>) (INSTANCE_NAME=<SID1>))) (DESCRIPTION= (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=<VIP2>)(PORT=1536)) (CONNECT_DATA= (SERVICE_NAME=ebs_<PDB>) (INSTANCE_NAME=<SID2>))))


Already registered database and instances with grid and can see entries also.

srvctl add database -db <DB_NAME> -oraclehome /u01/app/oracle/product/19.3.0/dbhome_1
srvctl add instance -db <DB_NAME> -instance <SID_1> -node <HOSTNAME_1>
srvctl add instance -db <DB_NAME> -instance <SID_2> -node <HOSTNAME_2>


++++

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production on 06-AUG-2023 19:51:50

Copyright (c) 1991, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=LISTENER_SCAN1)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER_SCAN1
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                05-AUG-2023 22:45:25
Uptime                    0 days 21 hr. 6 min. 25 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /u01/app/19.3.0/grid/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /u01/app/grid/diag/tnslsnr/oraebsdbdr01/listener_scan1/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=LISTENER_SCAN1)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=<SCAN_IP>)(PORT=1548)))
Services Summary...
Service "28182bc4cf6c4887e053b340d20a8b55" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "<SID_1>", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
  Instance "<SID_2>", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
Service "<DB_NAME>" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "<SID_1>", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
  Instance "<SID_2>", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "<PDB>_ebs_patch" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "<SID_1>", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
  Instance "<SID_2>", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
Service "<DB_NAME>XDB" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "<SID_1>", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
  Instance "<SID_2>", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "SYS$APPLSYS.WF_CONTROL.1126.<DOMAIN>" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "<SID_1>", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
  Instance "<SID_2>", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
Service "<PDB>" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "<SID_1>", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
  Instance "<SID_2>", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
Service "ebs_<PDB>" has 2 instance(s).
  Instance "<SID_1>", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
  Instance "<SID_2>", status READY, has 2 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```